# android:state_pressed is not working , pressing the button it is not not changing the color

Tags: android, button, colors, drawable

I have the following XML code in res/drawable and I set button background to this drawable. However when I pressed the button it is not not changing the color. Thanks for help

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/pink"/> <!-- pressed state -->
<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- default state -->
```

button :

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

color XML :

```
<color name="blue">#49B8C7</color>
<color name="pink">#FF8EB9</color>
```

Comment: hi you did set android:state_selected instead android:state_pressed in your xml. Please replace it.

Comment: Try with `<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pink"/> <!-- pressed state -->
<item android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- default state -->`

Comment: @Daniel.Wang state_pressed also is not working .

Comment: @rahat , it's not working as well .

Comment: try to set android:clickable="true" in Button tag.

Comment: added android:clickable="true" android:enabled="true" but still not working :((

Comment: seems to android:drawable="@color/pink" is not working in your device. In this case, you need to use shape in your button_bg.xml. Updated answer, please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue may caused by android:drawable="@color/pink". Seems to not working in color drawable.
In this case, Please like this.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"> <!-- pressed state -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"><solid android:color="@color/pink"/></shape>
    </item>
    <item> <!-- default state -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"><solid android:color="@color/blue"/></shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Button click event is occurred when press button?

Comment: selector xml name is buton_bg.xml

Comment: Please check button is enabled, if it's disabled, the background color is not changed when pressed. and try to set android:clickable="true" in Button tag.

Comment: added             android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true"

but still not working :((

Comment: seems to android:drawable="@color/pink" is not working in your device. In this case, you need to use shape in your button_bg.xml. Updated answer, please check it.

Comment: @ShadiSleman, Your case is very strange. you can check seperately. so you need to make drawable for each state @drawable/button_pressed and @drawable/button_normal in drawable folder. and then set it button background. If button background is working, you need to it combine one xml, <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /><item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />